# Is it appropriate to include relevant personal information?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently posted an answer; and I am writing this in order to ascertain the appropriateness of personal information which I usually omit to ensure an unbiased reaction to the media I produce. In my opinion, it was necessary to indicate I have a mental disability to give context to the information I provided. In my experience, people tend to overcompensate while attempting to be unbiased. As my Algebra professor put it one day in class,

> You dug yourself into a hole; dig yourself out.

Have I created a conundrum where people are afraid to be critical of my input due to the fact that their response may be misunderstood as biased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you wouldn't include it in your answer; you start your answer with *In my social groups...* which really means at some point in your answer you will need to explain what 'social group' that is.

In this case it was relevant to the subject of the question.

Had you included that information on a question like this [What's the meaning of "I'm slinging mad volume and fat stacking benjies"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/whats-the-meaning-of-im-slinging-mad-volume-and-fat-stacking-benjies) then the additional information on your personal situation is unnecessary.

Regarding *... people are [may be] afraid to be critical of my input...* I think you'll find people on this site are more than willing to criticise anything they can find fault with (and rightly so) and I doubt very much that anyone will consider your personal situation before downvoting or providing a critical comment. I certainly would not.